# Is it possible to use words as starting and ending points of excerpt parameters?

Tags: excerpt

I want to find a way for excerpt function to display exactly what i want inside a single post. the excerpt itself has starting and ending point as parameters to go and fetch the data. but what if i want to use words instead of them.

default:

$theExcerpt = get_the_content(); 
 echo substr($theExcerpt,0,200);

I want this:

$theExcerpt = get_the_content(); 
 echo substr($theExcerpt,'begining of paragraph', 'end of paragraph');

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more a PHP than a WP question. Try using a regular expression with [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php):

```
$theExcerpt = get_the_content();
$returnValue = preg_match('/(string01)(.*)(string02)/', $theExcerpt); 
echo $returnValue[0];
```

You have to replace *string01* and *string02* with your 'begining of paragraph' and 'end of paragraph'. There might be a more elegant way of using preg_match, but I think this will do the trick.

Don't forget to [escape the output](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/#escaping-securing-output)

Comment: Thanks bro, this really helped